# Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ObamPortal.Web.MvcApplication'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Source Error:**

*****Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ObamPortal.Web.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>*****

**Source File:  /global.asax    Line:  1**

I get this error when I am trying to debug an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 application using Visual Studio 2012. All the recommendations I saw here were for already deployed applications. Mind you, I am using Windows 7 as OS. How can I fix this?

My global.asax.cs is:

```
using ObamPortals.Core.Domain.Modules;
using ObamPortal.Web.Modules; 

namespace ObamPortal.Web 
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801 

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public override void Init() 
        {
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `Global.asax.cs` file to go with the `Global.asax`?

Comment: yes. i have Global.asax.cs

Comment: using ObamPortals.Core.Domain.Modules; 
 using ObamPortal.Web.Modules; 
 
  namespace ObamPortal.Web 
  { 
     // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
  // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

   public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
         public override void Init()
          {  
         }
  protected void Application_Start()
      {   
      }
  }
  }

Answer (score 4):

Try this following steps (any)

1.) Close IDE and reopen

2.) Perform a clean build

3.) change the output path in project settings for the web app to Bin (rather than bin/x86/Debug)

Comment: +1 Often when I get an error message like the above, a `Clean` and then `Rebuild` usually sorts it out.

Comment: done. ouput path is ObamPortal.Web\bin~. problem remains the same

Answer (score 3):

Did the app compile properly? Usually the Inherits would include Global in it as :  ObamPortal.Web.MvcApplication.Global

You need to make sure the Inherits matches exactly the namespace and class of the global.ascx.cs file.

Comment: the application compiled successfully. the error occurs when the web page is being rendered.

Comment: Have you tried copying the core code (inside the class definition) deleting the file, recompiling, re-creating the global.asax but let it do the naming, and then pasting your global event handlers back into the global.asax?